# How can I get a cell in a fixed column, but dynamic row, to change when another cell in the corresponding row is updated?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of data where I want Column AV to update with the word "Manual" in the row that corresponds to a row a change was made in.

Example:  I change the value in Y30, therefore I need AV30's value to update to "Manual".

Example:  I change the value in D21508, therefore I need AV21508's value to update to "Manual".

I'm a little rusty, but this is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim R As Range
   Set R = ActiveCell.EntireRow

   If Intersect(Target, R) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Application.EnableEvents = False
       R.Cells(1, 48).Value = "Manual"
   Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, your two examples don't seem to imply a "fixed" column (one in col A, another in col D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   'change the Range in the intersect for all the column you want to check.
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:AU")) Is Nothing Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Me.Cells(Target.Row, 48).Value = "Manual"
       Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah I caught that I was sending it to the first row.  I fixed it

Comment: @DavidZemens I just reread it myself, and I agree, but who knows as my new edit stands it does everything up to the column AU.  The OP can change it to anything he/she desires.

Comment: @DavidZemens My VB is probably terrible as I've been out of the game for a bit.  I see now how I referenced two different columns.

Comment: @DavidZemens  Works Perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @findwindow - and I've apparently just taken the day off :P

Comment: @BruceWayne you billionaire playboys don't work, everyday is a day off.

Comment: @BruceWayne shouldn't you be patrolling gotham?

Comment: Hahah Scott.  ... @findwindow - I ...uh...what?   Why would *I* patrol Gotham??     <_<  .....   >_>

Comment: How do I change my handle? Is there a mod that can overwrite it? Or do I have to start new account ;_;